# Can I use a modifier in Gsheets regexmatch()

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I have a formula in my spreadsheet:

```
=sum(filter(gaUsers,regexmatch(gaCategory,"new user funnel"),regexmatch(gaAction,B16)))
```

Cell B16 contains the string "Create Account". But in the raw data this shows as "create account". So, I'd like to enforce "ignore case" search. Something like:

```
regexmatch(gaAction,B16)/i // ignore case modifier.
```

Is this possible in Gsheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GDocs, you need to use a `CONCATENATE` function to append a subpattern to another pattern. Just using `+` won't do.

Instead of just `B16`, use

```
CONCATENATE("(?i)",B16)
```

And the whole formula would look like

```
=sum(filter(gaUsers,regexmatch(gaCategory,"new user funnel"),regexmatch(gaAction,CONCATENATE("(?i)",B16))))
```

Comment: Excellent that did it thanks. Curious, how/where did you learn to know how to do that in Gsheets?

Comment: I am using VBA quite regularly, and it occurred to me that GDocs have a similar concatenation function. I tested it in my Google account, and it worked.

Comment: This should also work: regexmatch(gaAction, "(?i)"&B16)

Answer (score 0):

According to https://re2.googlecode.com/hg/doc/syntax.html you can use `(?i)`:

Something like this should work..

```
regexmatch(gaAction,"(?i)"+B16)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but nope, returns "No matches are found" error. Matches do exist because when using regexmatch(gaAction,"create account") the formula does return many results